# ¿Cómo sobreponer un icono en un card?

Tags: css, card, mui

espero que estén bien, quisiera solicitar su ayuda mi pregunta es super sencilla, necesito obtener el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y he llegado a este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo es el siguiente:

```
{cardsText.map((item, i) => (
            <Grid  key={i} item xs={12} sm={4} md={3} lg={3} p={1} m={1}>
                <Card 
                    sx={{ 
                        backgroundColor: "#1B3665",
                        borderRadius: "1rem",
                        height: "12rem", 
                        position: "relative",
                    }}>
                    <CardActionArea sx={{ marginTop: "2rem" }}>
                    <img src={ imgIcon } alt="twoCards" 
                    style={{  
                        position: "absolute",
                        top: "-70px",
                        left: "-20px",
                        width: "60px",
                        height: "60px",
                    }}/>
                        <CardContent>
                            <Typography variant="body1" color="primary.contrastText">
                                {item.description}
                            </Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                    </CardActionArea>
                </Card>
            </Grid>
        ))}
```

como puedo sobre poner la imagen en el Card?... he probado con z-index pero no he conseguido el resultado esperado.

espero puedan ayudarme, de antemano les agradezco.

Saludos.